# Faster MySQL query when joining data from a non-Craft table to a Craft table

Tags: plugin-development, performance, mysql

I’m looking for a way to make a database query faster. The table `parts` has over 6 million rows. Each part row is associated with the `manufacturers` table (a couple hundred rows) by ID. When searching for results matching a query in a specific column (i.e.: partNumber or materialDescription) I have efficient queries that return results quickly.

The problem I’m having is when I’m doing an ALL search where the result can be in the `parts` table’s `partNumber` column or `materialDescription` column or the manufacturer’s title (which can only be determined by the `manufacturerID` from the part’s row which gets the `manufacturerCode` from the `manufacturers` table which can then get the manufacturer’s actual name by finding the entry in Craft’s content table `field_manufacturerCode` column. The results time is well past 20 seconds. Is there any way to make this database query more efficient assuming we can’t add the actual manufacturer’s name to the `manufacturers` table because the API we are getting the data from doesn’t include the manufacturer’s name?

```
SELECT p.id, p.manufacturerId, m.code as manufacturerCode, p.materialNumber, p.partNumber, p.materialDescription, c.title as manufacturerTitle
FROM `craft__parts` AS p
JOIN `craft__manufacturers` AS m ON p.manufacturerId = m.id
JOIN `craft_content` AS c ON m.code = c.field_manufacturerCode
WHERE p.partNumber like '%polymer%'
OR p.materialDescription like '%polymer%'
OR c.title like '%polymer%'
ORDER BY manufacturerTitle asc
```

Comment: This is going to be near impossible to help with in its current form. And honestly you'll probably be better off posting to something like dba.stackexchange.com as it's more of a query tuning question than directly related to Craft (and there are a lot more database experts there). If you go that route, I'd suggest sharing DDL for all involved tables including their indexes.

Comment: Thanks, I've provided more information on the dba.stackexchange like you suggested: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118801/faster-mysql-query-when-joining-data-from-multiple-tables

Comment: Two comments already... nice. :)

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Closing because this was cross-posted (and is a better fit on dba.SE)